# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "react-native-webrtc"

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, webrtc, version

[image]

## Package.json

```json
{
  "name": "Speed_Dating",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios --simulator=\"iPhone 13 Pro Max\"",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.14",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.9",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^5.1.0",
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^2.0.2",
    "@react-native-community/viewpager": "^5.0.11",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.2.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^14.2.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^14.2.1",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.2.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
    **"@types/react-native-webrtc": "^1.75.5",**
    "firebase": "^9.8.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.66.4",
    "react-native-code-push": "^7.0.4",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.1.3",
    "react-native-emoji-board": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.6.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-location": "^2.5.0",
    "react-native-material-menu": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-multiple-select": "^0.5.9",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^4.3.9",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.11.1",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.10.1",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.11.2",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
    "react-native-video": "^5.2.0",
    **"react-native-webrtc": "^1.94.1",**
    "react-native-webview": "^11.16.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.16.7",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.16.7",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "2.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.38",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.66.11",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "26.6.3",
    "jetifier": "^2.0.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.66.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

It's working fine in android but when i try to run in IOS then I run `pod install` after run  this throwing that error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***SOLUTION***

**Adjusting the supported platform version**

**IMPORTANT:** Make sure you are using CocoaPods 1.10 or higher.
You may have to change the **platform** field in your podfile.
**react-native-webrtc** doesn't support iOS < 12 Set it to '12.0' or above or you'll get an error when running **pod install**.

```html
platform :ios, '12.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that all old traces of Cocoapods are removed, I would suggest performing the following steps:

- Execute **"pod deintegrate"** command to remove any previous dependencies
- Run **"pod install"** command to install the required dependencies for
  the project
- If necessary, run **"pod update"** command to update the dependencies to
  their latest versions. Otherwise, you may skip this step if you
  already have the latest versions of the dependencies.

By following these steps, you can ensure that your project has the latest dependencies and is ready for development using the latest version of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

update platform :ios '11.0' to platform :ios '13.0' works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've came across with this problem and I solved it doing these steps:

Go to your Podfile file:

```
{PROJECT_FOLDER}/ios/Podfile
```

Search the line

> platform :ios,

and change the version to '13.0', it should be like this:

```
platform :ios, '13.0'
```

Then, inside a terminal, go to your {PROJECT_FOLDER} root and run:

```
cd ios && pod install && cd ..
```

That's it!